# Best approach to SaaS based CakePHP dynamic database login

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I am trying to decide on the best approach to designing a SaaS based system with a CakePHP application. I am currently using a Croogo based CakePHP app. We have been simply deploying an app to each client. What we want to do is setup a single environment where, based on initial login, a different (client) database is used. So, ideally, the CakePHP app would present a login screen (using a default database of clients). Based on login, dynamically switch the database being used based on the returned result. This way it's one app, and no subdomains or folders. I'm not even sure if this is possible though.

I think this would happen somewhere in the UsersController "after login" hook, switch databases...?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Well you should notice that there is the class ConnectionManager which handles the linkage between Models and the database. This class uses the data supplied in your DATABASE_CONFIG class of the config/database.php file.

I would say that a good option would be read the session before the connection is established. For example on the __construct of the DATABASE_CONFIG. Something like:

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'root',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'database',
    'prefix' => '',
    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);

public $test = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'user',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'test_database_name',
    'prefix' => '',
    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
public __construct(){
    App::uses('CakeSession');
    $database = CakeSession::read('Auth.User.database');
    if ($database){
        $this->default['database'] = $database;
    }

}

}
```